# trouble implementing method from inherited class -ios

Tags: ios, class, methods, model, call

I have looked through the other topics on this matter and I have not been able to determine my error.

I am very new to IOS programming.  I am trying to create a program that looks at the selected state of 2 buttons and determines whether the buttons selected state are the same.

I am currently trying to use a model to determine the buttons selected state and then pass the state to a label.  I have an error which says:

> No visible @interface for 'MatchTest' declares the selector 'doesItMatch'

I'd appreciate any help that may be offered.
Thanks!

this is the MatchTest.h file

```
//  MatchTest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MatchTest : NSObject
@end
```

this is the MatchTest.m file

```
//  MatchTest.m
#import "MatchTest.h"

@implementation MatchTest

-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString* tempString;

    if(sender.isSelected)
    {
        tempString = @"selected";
    }
    else
    {
        tempString = @"not selected";
    }

    return tempString;
}
@end
```

this is the MatchViewController.h file

```
//  MatchViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MatchTest.h"
@interface MatchViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

this is the MatchViewController.m file

```
//  MatchViewController.m
#import "MatchViewController.h"
@interface MatchViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *matchLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MatchTest *match;

@end

@implementation MatchViewController

-(MatchTest *)match
{
    if(!_match) _match = [[MatchTest alloc] init];
    return _match;
}

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
    self.matchLabel.text = [self.match doesItMatch:sender];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare `doesItMatch` method in MatchTest.h file
like

in MatchTest.h

```
-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender;
```

compiler is not able to file doesItMatch method's declaration in .h file that's why that error is there.

Comment: You're awesome!  Thanks so much.  Fixed the issue.

do you always need to declare methods like that in the .h file.  I'm new to C based programming in general.

Comment: Yes you need to declare, specially when you are calling it out side the class itself. but if you are calling it in the same class it is not required. if at all declaring method in .h file is good programming habit.

Comment: accepted. wouldn't have known about that either

thanks for the reply about the .h question also!

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined your method `-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender` in  **MatchTest.h file**.
You are importing **MatchTest.h file** in **MatchViewController.h file** so you need to define your methods or variables or property to make available this method.

Therefore according to your error log viewController wasn't able to find the interface where this method is declared.